# Changing a value according to current date

Tags: android

I have two dates in string format and stored it using shared preference.the first date(current date)is set to date picker date and second one is the date after adding 41 days to the first date.In a button i have to get the difference between the two dates in days.And it is stored using shared preference.The problem is that i have to decrement the difference between these two dates according to each current date.How can do that?please help...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.end;
//import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.enddate;
import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.imageView;
import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.myImageViewText;
//import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.startdate;
import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.textView3;

/**
 * Created by aiswarya on 3/24/2017.
 */

public class Fasting extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton backb;
    ImageButton reset;
    TextView startdate,enddate;
    ImageView remaining;
    TextView remainingtext;
    SharedPreferences myprefs;
    public String dayys;
    public  long from,to;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitydate);
        backb=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        reset= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        // startdate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        // enddate= (TextView) findViewById(textView3);
        remaining=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        //remainingtext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);





        backb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Fasting.this,
                        Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startdate.setText("START DATE");
                enddate.setText("END DATE");
                remainingtext.setText("REMAINING DAYS");


            }
        });

        myprefs=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        init();


    }



    public void selectFrom(View v) {
        final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(Fasting.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {


                Log.d("date", dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 41);

                ((TextView)findViewById(textView3)).setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));



                long from = today.getTimeInMillis();
                long to = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                int days = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Math.abs(from - to));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DAYS = " + days, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final String dayss=String.valueOf(days);

                remaining.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        remainingtext.setText(""+dayss+" DAYS");

                    }
                });

            }
        }, today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dp.show();
    }

    private  void init(){
        startdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        enddate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        remainingtext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);


        readPreferences();
    }

    public void onSave(View view) {
        String start=startdate.getText().toString();
        String end=enddate.getText().toString();
        String rem=remainingtext.getText().toString();
        //int ageText=Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myprefs.edit();
        editor.putString("keyname",start);
        editor.putString("keyage",end);
        editor.putString("keyrem",rem);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void onReset(View view) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myprefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        readPreferences();

    }

    public void readPreferences(){
        String stl= myprefs.getString("keyname","");
        startdate.setText(stl);
        //int vall=myprefs.getInt("keyage",0);
        String vall=myprefs.getString("keyage","");
        enddate.setText(String.valueOf(vall));
        String remdays=myprefs.getString("keyrem","");
        remainingtext.setText(String.valueOf(remdays));





    }



}
```

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context="com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.Fasting">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linir_back"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linir_back"
        android:src="@drawable/back_button"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FASTING"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="visible"

    android:onClick="selectFrom"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

    android:text="START DATE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"

    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="END DATE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/submit4resized1"
    android:onClick="onSave"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    />


<ImageButton

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:src="@drawable/resetbutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:onClick="onReset" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="216dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:onClick="showDiff"
        android:src="@drawable/new1"
        android:layout_marginRight="63dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="REMAINING DAYS"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```